# Date column comparison in UDF failing with Type Error python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a UDF function which compares 2 date columns with last date of every year. Depending on the difference between these columns i need to assign a status.I am getting output when i use show function but while writing the same is failing with type error

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,IntegerType,DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,datediff, to_date, lit,year
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def getStatus(x,CRE_DT,cont_DT):
    if x < CRE_DT :
        return 'Not Active'
    elif cont_DT == '9999-12-31':
        return 'Active'  
    elif (x > CRE_DT )  & (cont_DT > x ) & (cont_DT != '9999-12-31'):
        return 'Active'  
    return 'Stop' 
func_udf = udf(getStatus,StringType())
for i in range(2015, 2022):
  df_tmp = df.withColumn(f'Date_{i}', lit(f'{i}-12-31')).withColumn(f'{i}-12-31', func_udf(to_date(f'Date_{i}'),df.CRE_DT,df.cont_DT)).drop(f'Date_{i}')
  df=df_tmp
```

Error while writing the dataframe:

caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'', from , line 7. Full traceback below:

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe? As the error says the comparison doesn't work because one of the entries you are comparing with is not a `datetime.date`

Comment: Thank you @Luke, Identified the issue ,there was a single null value in the CRE_DT column causing the issue.